# IOrderedEnumerable to vb.net IOrderedEnumerable Conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, iorderedenumerable

```
Private Sub UpdateListBox(message As String)
    Dim beeGroups As IOrderedEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of BeeState, Bee)) = From beeGroup In From bee In Me.world.BeesGroup bee By bee.CurrentStateOrder By beeGroup.KeybeeGroup
    Me.listBox1.Items.Clear()

    For Each beeGroup As IGrouping(Of BeeState, Bee) In beeGroups
        Dim s As String
        s = If(beeGroup.Count() = 1, String.Empty, "s")

        Me.listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(beeGroup.Key) & ": " & beeGroup.Count() & " bee" & s)

        If beeGroup.Key <> BeeState.Idle OrElse beeGroup.Count() <> Me.world.Bees.Count() OrElse Me.framesRun <= 0 Then
            Continue For
        End If

        Me.listBox1.Items.Add("Simulation ended: all bees are idle")
        Me.toolStripButtonStartSimulation.Text = "Simulation ended."
        Me.statusStrip1.Items(0).Text = "Simulation ended"
        Me.timer1.Enabled = False
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm absolutely stuck at this error in the conversion of a `c#` project to `vb.net`.

I know in `c#` it goes like this

```
IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<BeeState, Bee>> beeGroups = from bee in this.world.Bees
                                                                 group bee by bee.CurrentState
                                                                 into beeGroup orderby beeGroup.Key select beeGroup;
```

But once converted into `vb.net` it tries to state everything on one line with the fewest amount of declarations.

While also in `c#` you can get away with
`c#`:

```
foreach (IGrouping<BeeState, Bee> beeGroup in beeGroups)
```

vb.net tries to declare the for statement within itself:

```
For Each group As var In beeGroups
```

Comment: `I'm absolutely stuck at this error in the conversion of a c# project to vb.net` What error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub UpdateListBox(message As String)
    Dim beeGroups = From bee In Me.world.Bees
                    Group By bee.CurrentState Into beeGroup = Group
                    Order By beeGroup.Key

    Me.listBox1.Items.Clear()

    For Each beeGroup In beeGroups
        Dim beeCount = beeGroup.Count ' to avoid reevaluation
        Dim s = If(beeCount >= 1, String.Empty, "s")

        Me.listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(beeGroup.Key) & ": " & beeCount & " bee" & s)

        If beeGroup.Key <> BeeState.Idle OrElse beeCount <> Me.world.Bees.Count OrElse Me.framesRun <= 0 Then
            Continue For
        End If

        Me.listBox1.Items.Add("Simulation ended: all bees are idle")
        Me.toolStripButtonStartSimulation.Text = "Simulation ended."
        Me.statusStrip1.Items(0).Text = "Simulation ended"
        Me.timer1.Enabled = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'For Each' statement is correct (both your C# and VB versions declare the iterator variable within the loop header), however the VB LINQ query should be:

```
Dim beeGroups As IOrderedEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of BeeState, Bee)) = From bee In Me.world.Bees
                                                                      Group bee By bee.CurrentState Into beeGroup = Group
                                                                      Order By CurrentState
                                                                      Select beeGroup
```

Or user Option Infer On:

```
Dim beeGroups = From bee In Me.world.Bees
                Group bee By bee.CurrentState Into beeGroup = Group
                Order By CurrentState
                Select beeGroup
```

Comment: `Select` isn't needed in VB.Net by default the query returns what is currently in the query scope (in that case only `beeGroup`). Also you forgot to qualify `CurrentState` by `bee.` in the `Order By` clause ;)

Comment: After the `select beeGroup from Dim beeGroups`. It acts like the `select  beeGroup` not not even exist when i state afterwards `For Each beeGroup In beeGroup` . I can see beeGroup is declared within beeGroup and the error is confusion. Am i going to this the wrong way to use IEnumerable and that to declare? Thank you for the help before :)

Comment: Ok the error is that it's not being declared, my confusion is to large to fit into a variable :D. But is their a way to declare the beeGroup before beeGroups, or a better way if you can think of one.